# CSS seclect element by id containing query string

Tags: php, css, url, css-selectors

I'm theming a website http://www.complementchic.com

so in my css, I've set css for the body to resize images at

http://www.complementchic.com/modules/vente_flash/flashSale.php

```
 #module-vente_flash-flashSale
```

but when I have the page switching language through 
php post the url becomes:

http://www.complementchic.com/modules/vente_flash/flashSale.php?&id_lang=2

and as a result my body id in css is changing to

```
 #module-vente_flash-flashSale?&id_lang=2
```

and I'm unable to use this ID in my css stylesheet -

So, a) is there a way for me to use this ID in my stylesheet or fix this issue,

Comment: Provide code where you crate `#module-vente_flash-flashSale` from url. Also, it's not so good practise to create divs id names by urls

Comment: I didn't create the module :-) but it seems the div name by url might be useful for theming diff language pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using CSS attribute selector:

**HTML:**

```
<body id="module-vente_flash-flashSale?&id_lang=2">
This is a text here
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body[id="module-vente_flash-flashSale?&id_lang=2"] {
  background-color: red; /* for example */
}
```

**[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ujuluc/1/edit)** demo

Comment: this sounds like it will work I will try and let you know thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP explode function for this ex:

```
$idetails = explode("?&", 'flashSale?&id_lang=2');

$id=$idetails[0];

value of $id is flashSale
```